# Passing data onClick from child component to another child component in React.JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, react-props, children

I'm trying to render the selected li (mapped in a child component) in an another child component.
So you have the following structure (very simple):

---

Parent Component (Parent.JS)

- ➥ First Child called Title.JS (that should render the title selected from the Second Child, which will contain the menu)
- ➥ Second Child called Menu.JS (which contains the menu)

---

The exercise I'm trying to do and to understand here, is how to ****pass data(s) between children using props**** (in case the value goes through the parent).

**Parent.JS**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Child from './Child'
import Title from './Menu'


function Parent() {
    const [word, setWord] = useState('Parent');

    return (
        <div>
            <Title />
            <Menu changeWord={word => setWord(word)}/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Parent
```

**Title.JS**

```
import React from 'react'

function Title(props) {
    return (
        <div>
           //Here I tell the code to print "Nothing selected" 
           //until I don't choose a link in the menu. 
           {props.title ? <h1>{props.title}</h1> : <h1>Nothing selected</h1>}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Title
```

**Menu.JS**

```
import React from 'react'

const data = [
    {title: "Home"},
    {title: "About"},
    {title: "Contact"},
]

function Menu(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            {data.map((item) => {
                return <li onClick={() => props.changeWord(props.children)}>{item.title}</li>
            })}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Menu
```

Of course, **App,JS** is simplified.

```
import Parent from './Parent'

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Parent />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I'm so close..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `changeWord` you want to pass the `item` you're mapping through as opposed to `props.children`

So your `Menu` should look like this

```js
import React from 'react';

const data = [{ title: 'Home' }, { title: 'About' }, { title: 'Contact' }];

function Menu(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((item) => {
        return <li onClick={() => props.changeWord(item)}>{item.title}</li>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
export default Menu
```

Your `Parent` should pass the `word.title` state value into the `Title` like this

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Child from './Child'
import Title from './Menu'


function Parent() {
    const [word, setWord] = useState('Parent');

    return (
        <div>
            <Title title={word.title}/>
            <Menu changeWord={word => setWord(word)}/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Parent
```

NB: You should remove your initial state value of `'Parent'` because `word` is an object now and you may get an error when trying to access `word.title`.